# How can i distinguish between two columns in a table that use the same lookup table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns in a table, which are AssignedStatus and ReviewedStatus. I have a lookup table called Status, which has the StatusID and StatusName columns. AssignedStatus and ReviewedStatus store the StatusID values. So far I have

```
JOIN STATUS ON DATA.ASSIGNEDSTATUS = STATUS.STATUSID 
AND DATA.REVIEWEDSTATUS = STATUS.STATUSID
```

but I don't know how to write the Select statement so that I can display the AssignedStatus and ReviewedStatus with the appropriate StatusName.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use table aliases:

```
select t.*, sa.? as assigned_???, sr.? as reviewed_???
from atable t left join
     status sa
     on t.assignedstatus = sa.statusid left join
     status sr
     on t.reviewedstatus = sr.statusid;
```

The `?` is for the column you want from the reference table.  The `???` is just to remind you to put in a meaningful alias.